# Что делает 9-ая строка, где "elif s[:i] + s[i + 1:] == (s[:i] + s[i + 1:])[::-1]:"? Подробно пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, срез

```
s = input()
i = 0
j = len(s) - 1
while i < j and s[i] == s[j]:
    i += 1 # Поиск двух различных символов i и j, равноудалённых от концов строки
    j -= 1
if i >= j:
    print("строка – уже палиндром") # дело в шляпе
elif s[:i] + s[i + 1:] == (s[:i] + s[i + 1:])[::-1]:    
    print(i + 1) # можно удалить символ i
elif s[:j] + s[j + 1:] == (s[:j] + s[j + 1:])[::-1]:
    print("это j")
    print(j + 1) # можно удалить символ j
else:
    print(0) # а из него уже ничего не получиться(
```

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите, в этой строке `s[:i] + s[i + 1:] == (s[:i] + s[i + 1:])[::-1]` есть один повторяющийся код `s[:i] + s[i + 1:]` и срез `[::-1]`.

`s[:i] + s[i + 1:]` это два среза строки с игнорированием символа, имеющего индекс `i` (`s[:i]` вернет строку, не включая индекс `i`, а с `s[i + 1:]` и так понятно), для наглядности:

```
s = '12345'
i = 2
print(s[:i] + s[i + 1:])
# 1245
```

А вот срез `[::-1]` используется только для возврата строки в обратном порядке:

```
s = '12345'
print(s[::-1])
# 54321
```